# VS code Intellisense support in PHTML-files for inline css / inline javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio Code since a few days and I was wondering if it is possible to have support for Intellisense inside inlined css-blocks and/or inlined javascript in '*.phtml*'-files.

[image: As you can see there is only support for php]

I could not find a solution online only a few people complaining about this not working from a few months back but I nothing that worked for me.
It would really help me a lot if someone has any idea how to solve this or at least a step in the right direction, or if I have to move the css and js into external files (of course thats better(!) but thats not the point here **;)**)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set a `type` attribute on the style block?

Comment: @Brainfeeder yes I did! The problem is not me being unable to properly use css and js inline, but the actual support from VS code.

Comment: I use Aptana and noticed code hinting stopped working for style and script blocks without a `type` attibute, thought it might be the same problem in VS code. Sorry I can't help you out on this, I'm not a VS code user :)

Comment: Use `.php` instead? `.phtml` was the standard file extension for PHP 2 but is nowadays rarely used.

Comment: @Red This is not possible, it is a huge project and I cant just convert stuff back and forth unfortunately. Also I am not even sure if that would solve the problem :/

Comment: Does anything change when you name the files as `.html`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I cant just change the file-ending. It is a php document, not html..

Comment: I am not asking you to change, I just asking to rename one and see if it fixes the issue or not

Comment: @TarunLalwani In actual html-files the support works without a problem. Thats why I am absolutely clueless of why it wont work in *.phtml.

Comment: I would add a custom file association in config as `"files.associations": {
  "*.phtml": "html"
 }`. And see if it helps. Restart vscode just to be sure. Also if `html` doesn't help I will give `php` also a shot

Comment: @TarunLalwani It was a good idea but now it fails the php-support.. have tried adding both but this unfortunately also would not work. I am absolutely clueless..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169241/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-informant09).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me after 2 changes in `vscode`.

**User settings**

I added below to the user settings

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.phtml": "php"
    },
```

**Extension**

Installing the intelliphense extension

[image: Extension]

And now both `php` as well as `css` intellisense works

[image: PHP]

[image: CSS]

Make sure you have no other conflicting extension enabled which may cause issue.

Also do have a look at the below open thread

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/670